# Sending text from my program to an existing program textbox

Tags: c#

Here is the situation. At my job, we use an existing program that allows us to scan barcodes into a record set. The issue is, to create this record set we have to scan each item separately. We click an add button which brings up a textbox and we scan the barcodes into it (or it can be typed in)

To avoid having to do this, I've built a program in C# that creates a list of barcodes and I was looking for a way to just set up a simple copy and paste type setup that would copy a barcode, paste it into the existing programs textbox and maybe send a return char so it will be ready for the next barcode. It would simply send over each barcode one at a time till it had gone through the list.

I have control over my c# program, but the work program isn't built by me and I don't have access to the code or any apis it uses. Could someone suggest a solution that might work for this? I found something called SendMessage, but I'm not completely certain how it works since it says I need to search for the process first.

Comment: Welcome to the rabbit hole.  Pull up a p/invoke and stay awhile.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem using http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/. 
It simply allows you to automate key-presses so that you can:

1. Read the content from your file with barcodes
2. Press a key in you other software that opens up the input window
3. Input the barcode
4. Press return

I have done this for programs with no API, and it works great as a way of avoiding manual typing. Looks a bit ugly, though!

Comment: That's a nice project.  But it appears only to send keys to the active window.  Does it also wrap the calls to send keys to a specific window?

Comment: @Will, no, sorry, it does not send to a specific window.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SendMessage, you can use spy++ to search for the class and name of the textbox, which will allow you to get a handle to the textbox. I'm sure I've seen an API call for settext, but I can't seem to find it at the moment. You can however use the messages WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYDOWN to simulate data entry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
```

Used as such:

```
SendMessage(textboxHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, KeyCode, null);
SendMessage(textboxHandle, WM_KEYUP, KeyCode, null);
```

Keycode list;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: SendMessage(textboxHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, text)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) framework which is part of .NET 3+.

You would then use a tool such [UISpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx) to extract the needed information relative to the text field in question which you can latch onto within your C# application and the UI Automation framework.

An example exists via a [MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163288.aspx).

Comment: Ok, this works for sending the text. Is there anyway to send a keypress using UI Automation? I searched around, but haven't had much success. Or would I need to use keypress or sendmessage? I need to simulate a Keypress for Enter as there is no button that does that function. Thanks

Comment: @Chris You need an exposed UI element to make use of UI Automation as it needs to reside within the visual tree for the framework to access it. If there is no button perhaps it is being committed when focus is lost within the text box. Not certain if it would work but have you tried placing a /r/n within your SetValue after your text? You could also try calling SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}"); after your SetValue on the text.